# Imposing parallel maximum running time for MatLab function in loops

Tags: multithreading, matlab, loops, timer, parallel-processing

Fresh to the Matlab, not so familiar with coding and programing in MatLab.

```
function fucx()
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:3
        for k = 1:3
            try
                %MainFuc()

                %TimerFuc()
                time = cputime;
                time = cputime-time;
                a = timer;
                set (a, 'executionMode', 'fixedRate')
                set (a,'timerfcn','disp(time)')
                start(a)
                timeStop = time;
                if (timeStop>60) % in seconds
                    disp('RunOutOfTime: Program terminated');
                    stop(a)
                    break;
                end;

            catch
                %%Err()
            end
        end
     end
end
end
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

%%Update%%

I see the recommended answer as below. I've tried this one.

```
start = tic;

for i=1:1000000
    if (mod(i,1000)==0)
        if (toc(start) > 2) % here, 2 seconds
            error('Took toooo loooong');
        end
    end
end
```

The thing I want to assure is that the timer or tic function running in parallel to the MainFuc() and know when to stop the loop.

Comment: Could you reopen my question? @rayryeng

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "tic" and "toc" functions from matlab, see the documentation here [Matlab tic function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html?refresh=true). 
When you call "tic", the timer restarts, and every time you call "toc" it gives you the time in seconds since the last "tic". Then if you call "tic" another time, the timer will restart.

Here is the code you need.

```
a = 0;
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:3
        tic;
        for k = 1:10^7
            try
                %MainFuc()
                a = a + 1;
            catch
                %%Err()
            end
            %TimerFuc()
            time = toc;
            if (time>2) % in seconds
                disp('RunOutOfTime: Program terminated');
                break;
            end;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I did this at the first time. But it won't allow the code to run in a parallel way. Because this is running out of the MainFuc(). It will only know the time after the MainFuc() is finished.

Comment: If I understand well, you want MainFunction() to stop executing when the time is exceeded?
You could try to put the tic variable as an input to the MainFunction to keep track of the time.
Otherwise, you would have to use timers and events in Matlab, but it is beyond my expertise.

Comment: Right, I want the MainFunc() to be stopped once the executing time is reached to a threshold.

Comment: What is inside your MainFunc()? are there any loops?

Comment: It is huge collection of model setting, study, and solutions. No loops. Was thinking directly put tic/toc function into the MainFuc(). But not sure if MatLab internally would work the way that I want it to. Because We do not know which step or code line the infinite time was trapped in. Cant simply put the tic/toc function with it if it is not determined in parallel.